# Next.js typescript next.config.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I try to use Next.js with TypeScript and I need add custom configuration. I had created a next.config.js file but looks like Next.js doesn't load it. For example custom environments variable unavailable. Here's my next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [
    optimizedImages,
    {
      /* config for next-optimized-images */
      optimizeImages: false,
    },
  ],
  {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    // images: {
    //   domains: ['localhost:3000'],
    //   path: `uploads/_next/image`
    // imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384]
    // },
    env: {
      baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001",
      apiUrl: "http://localhost:5000",
    },
  },

  // your other plugins here
]);
```

For example when I try to access baseUrl like process.env.baseUrl I get an error

> Server Error
> Error: baseUrl is undefined.

Same config is working correct with JavaScript version of Next.js.

So what I do wrong?

Comment: You should setup environment variables using `.env` files. I'd recommend a read through [Environment Variables in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables).

Comment: Yes I did already. Thanks. But my question is about how to use custom configuration with TypeScript version?

Comment: If you've set it up with the `.env` file then you don't need to set the environment variables in `next.config.js`. Just access your variables as they appear in the `.env` file, e.g., `process.env.YOUR_ENV_VAR`. This is unrelated to the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to typescript. Typescript does not have any control over next.js it does check types. In current next.js set up, when you install, if you choose to use typescript, next.js already configures typescript for you.

Variables that you are using in .env files are going to be accessible only by the server. If you need to set up environment variables for the client, then you set them in next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    // this is where you add custom configuration for webpack
    return config;
  },
 
  env: {
  // this is where you set env variables for the client side
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    
  },
  pwa: {
   // this where you add progressive web app setting
    dest: "public",
    swSrc: "service-worker.js",
   },
};
```